# My fullsatck JS application does not work in production on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql, heroku

I have created my first FullStack JS app. REACT for the front port :3000, NODE for the Back port 3001 and postgresql for database. And is also the first time I use Heroku !

My app called **philosophybooks** my database postgres is **livres** with one table **books** on this table 13 rows, 13 books in my db it's just for exemple :
`author, title, date_of_parution, cover`  cover is just a string I've a folder `illustrations_books`  in my frontend part of my app in this folder I have all images of the cover book

**With CLI on windows I have well push all my app with my database all is well on Heroku.** In front I've run a build folder and I have copy this one in back part of my app.
When I start `heroku local web` all work perfectly on `http:localhost:5000`
but when I launch my app not locally I have a console error

> GET https://philosophybooks.herokuapp.com/livres 503 (Service Unavailable)

in front part in package.json I've`"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"`

> little part of **index.js**

```js
...   
app.use(express.static('build'))
...   

//Entry point API 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('My app is well connected and endpoint is OK')
})
//READ ALL
app.get("/livres", (req, res) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY id ASC', (err, results) => {
        if (!err)
            res.status(200).json(results.rows)
        else
            console.log(err)
    })
})

...
...  

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`[Express] is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

> Little part of **Livres.jsx** in front part

```js
...
...  

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsError(false)
            try {
                const result = await axios('/livres') /* 'http://localhost:3001/livres' */
                setData(result.data)
            } catch (error) {
                setIsError(true)
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])  
...  
...
```

> **config.js**

```js
require('dotenv').config()

const { Pool } = require('pg')

/* const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,

}) */
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

const connectionString = `postgresql://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
  ssl: isProduction,
})
module.exports = { pool }
```

I have also a Procfile file `web: node index.js`

> **package.json** backend part

```
{
    "name": "philosophybooks",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "bibliothéque philosophique",
    "main": "index.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.x",
        "npm": "6.x"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon index.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "NODEJS",
        "JAVASCRIPT",
        "ES6"
    ],
    "author": "LC",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "compression": "^1.7.4",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "helmet": "^4.1.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "pg": "^8.3.3"
    }
}
```

Render `heroku local web`
[image: when all works perfectly in local heroku]

Render in prod`https://philosophybooks.herokuapp.com/`
[image: render production]

> I have to make a mistake that I don’t see or forget something, can you help me? if you need to see something else tell me. Thank you in advance for your help

---

**EDIT Octobre 18, 2020**

> My database on HEROKU and via CLI pg:psql
> [image: on HEROKU]

[image: Database view via pg:psql CLI]

Comment: Hey @Parad0xJ, do you have the entire code on github?

Comment: Hi @HenryLy No, I just initiated the repository with CLI but I did not push it on Github. Immediately I go to the sport, I will be back in 3 hours, I will put my code on Github when I get back, and I will put the link here. I've tried a lot of different things but still can't see my app on Heroku correctly.Thanks for your help

Comment: @HenryLy all my code is here : [philosophybooks on GitHub](https://github.com/Parad0xJ/philosophybooks)

Comment: awesome! Can you also pass me your database schema? I need to print it into heroku so it can deploy correctly

Comment: I was able to successfully deploy your application , but I think the problem was because you didn't add your table to heroku. Once you pass me your table I think I can have a closer look at the problem

Comment: Great ! Thanks for your help @HenryLy 
I just edited my first post, at the end of this one, I added two images, you can see that my database is well on Heroku. You can download my database here  [livres.backup via dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzx66rkh6bmg5kl/livres.backup?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonjour Parad0xJ,

**PROBLEM:**

It wasn't working because you were assigning an ssl certificate that wasn't verified. If you look at the heroku error carefully you will notice this error.

```
Error: self signed certificate
'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
  ssl: isProduction,  <=========== unverified self signed certificate
})
```

**SOLUTION**

Get rid of the ssl property in your pool configuration. Heroku already provides you a ssl so all you have to do is determine whether you want to disable or require it. You can read more [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-ssl-with-postgresql)

```
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
  sslmode: isProduction ? "require" : "disable"
})
```

Also you need to add the * route to the bottom because when it is at the top no other routes can be access:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => { //<=========== Should be at the bottom of all routes
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "frontend/build/index.html"));
});
```

Here is all the configuration in this git repo :

https://github.com/l0609890/philosophybook/invitations

Comment: Overall I love the philosophy theme!

Comment: I had seen this error in the logs but I did not understand where it came from, I understand now. But even with **sslmode** I still can't see my app on heroku. I love Philosophy to !!

Comment: There must be another error, I have a doubt with these lines of code there would not be an error on this side there too?      `//app.use(express.static('./frontend/build'))`  
`//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))`  
`if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend/build")));
}`  
`app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "frontend/build/index.html"));
}); `

Comment: Interesting, I have to head out a few hours but I will get back to checking this problem out for you.

Comment: hey @Parad0xJ, I saw that you added your * route at the top so no other routes can access it. Here is the code I deployed and I also attached the actual website :https://github.com/l0609890/philosophybook/invitations

Comment: It works perfectly on your side it’s great, I understood my mistakes I corrected all that. I spent more time figuring out how to deploy on Heroku than coding my app, it’s very annoying!! I put in resolution I’m fed up, it still doesn’t work. Really a huge Thanks for your help you corrected a lot of mistakes I had made and with the explanations, you were really super efficient. a big thank you for the time you spent helping me

Comment: Haha thanks man!, I what to thank you too for making it as easy as possible. Notice you are trying to get into the web development field so best of luck with that mate!

Comment: Bonjour @HenryLy I took back my code with my head rested, and I found the solution. Well you helped me a lot too. Once again a big thank you to you.  [philosophybooks on Heroku](https://philosophybooks.herokuapp.com/)